# Can a strict right fold be implemented in a single loop?

Tags: algorithms, recursion, functional-programming, loops

A strict left fold is straightforward to implement as a loop, rather than with recursion:

```
foldl(fn, acc, list)
    loop until empty(list)
        acc ← fn(acc, head(list))
        list ← tail(list)

    return acc
```

For a strict right fold, the best I've been able to come up with is by maintaining a stack of partially applied functions, which gets unrolled at the end to evaluate the accumulator:

```
foldr(fn, acc, list)
    stack ← empty stack

    loop until empty(list)
        stack push λx ↦ fn(head(list), x)
        list ← tail(list)

    loop until empty(stack)
        acc ← (stack pop)(acc)

    return acc
```

The size of the stack, when full, will be the same size as the input list; so it has to iterate through twice. Moreover, a stack of partially applied functions is hardly different from the call stack that would be created when using recursion, so it doesn't really achieve much.

It is possible to implement a right fold using a left fold:

```
foldr(fn, acc, list)
    return foldl(λx,y ↦ fn(y, x), acc, reverse(list))
```

However, that `reverse` still implies a second iteration.

Is it possible to do better?

---

**EDIT** "Single loop" is a bit ambiguous. I suppose my question is: Can a strict right fold be implemented in $O(n)$ time and $O(1)$ space, without recursion, like a strict left fold can?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have solved this! After reading more about it, it seems my hunch about trampolining -- see my comment from my previous answer -- is exactly what I want. So here's what we do:

1. Convert the recursive `foldr` into continuation-passing style.
2. Wrap each function evaluation into a thunk so no recursion actually happens; instead each invocation returns the next element in the sequence.
3. Write a trampoline function (just a loop) that unrolls this sequence to give the final result.

Recursive `foldr`:

```
foldr(fn, acc, list)
    match list
        empty     => return acc
        otherwise => return fn(head(list), foldr(fn, acc, tail(list))
```

Convert to CPS:

```
foldr'(fn, acc, list, k)
    match list
        empty     => return k(acc)
        otherwise => return foldr'(fn, acc, tail(list), λx ↦ k(fn(head(list), x)))
```

Wrap the function evaluation in thunks (argument-less lambda functions):

```
foldr'(fn, acc, list, k)
    match list
        empty     => return k(acc)
        otherwise => return λ ↦ foldr'(fn, acc, tail(list), λx ↦ λ ↦ k(fn(head(list), x)))
```

Write a trampolining function:

```
trampoline(f)
    loop while thunk(f)
        f ← f()
    return f
```

Stitch it all together:

```
foldr(fn, acc, list)
    return trampoline(foldr'(fn, acc, list, λx ↦ x))
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have come up with a solution, but I'm not convinced. We observe that, from `foldr(fn, acc, list)`, we can rewrite the intermediary steps as a series of single-valued functions:

$$
\begin{align}
eval_0 &: x \mapsto fn(list_0,x) \\
eval_1 &: x \mapsto eval_0(fn(list_1, x)) \\
\vdots \\
eval_n &: x \mapsto eval_{n-1}(fn(list_n, x))
\end{align}
$$

Then, where $n$ is the length of $list$:

$$
foldr(fn, acc, list) = eval_n(acc)
$$

For example:

$$
\begin{align}
foldr((x,y)\mapsto x-y,0,[1,2,3]) &= eval_3(0) \\
                   &= eval_2(3-0) \\
                   &= eval_1(2-(3-0)) \\
                   &= 1-(2-(3-0)))
\end{align}
$$

So the loop algorithm looks something like:

```
foldr(fn, acc, list)
    eval ← λx ↦ x

    loop until empty(list)
        eval ← λx ↦ eval(fn(head(list), x))
        list ← tail(list)

    return eval(acc)
```

I say I'm "not convinced" as implementing this is tricky. The `eval ← λx ↦ eval(...)` line is self-referential: informally we know it means "eval becomes a function of the *previous* eval", but in reality this gets interpreted as infinite recursion. So you end up having to keep a stack in memory either way.

Comment: I feel like "trampolining" might be what I'm missing, but I'm only vaguely aware of the term and its association to problems such as these. I don't know if it's appropriate, or how to implement it...